# can i compute the inverse mod m by inverting the prime factors?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse, prime-factorization

I have $a \in \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{mZ}$ and $a = p_1 * p_2$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ ($p_i$ are primes).

Furthermore, it holds $gcd(a,m) = 1$, so there exists an $a^{-1} \in \mathbb{Z/mZ}$.

Would be ok to write $a^{-1} = (p_1 * p_2)^{-1} = p_1^{-1} * p_2^{-1} \mod m$?

If yes, why?

If no, please submit a counter-example.

I'm not able to find anything on Wikipedia or somewhere else.

By the way: I know that you normally use the extended Euclidian Algorithm to compute the inverse.

Comment: you can because the group is abelian, but in general for groups the correct law is $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks! I already forgot that simple fact about inverting a product.